# PyGame frame rate with keyboard input

Tags: python, pygame

Using PyGame, I want to create a moving square which moves in a grid, controlled by keyboard presses of the arrows. So, pressing the "up" key moves the square to the cell directly upwards, pressing the "right" key moves the square to the cell directly to the right, etc.

In my loop, I use `pygame.time.wait(x)`, to pause for `x` ms. However, choosing the correct value for `x` is proving difficult. If `x` is too large (e.g. 1000), then the square does not respond immediately, and I actually have to hold down the key to get it to move. But if `x` is too small (e.g. 10), then the square will move several times in a row whenever I press a key. But I just want the square to move once for every key press. How can I do this? Thanks!

Below is the important part of my code:

```
    x = 100
    current_pos = [0, 0]

    while True:

        pygame.event.pump()  # process event queue
        is_key_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if is_key_pressed[pygame.K_UP]:
            current_pos[1] -= 1

        elif is_key_pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            current_pos[0] += 1

        elif is_key_pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            current_pos[1] += 1

        elif is_key_pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            current_pos[0] -= 1

        show_map(current_pos)

        pygame.time.wait(x)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of checking the state of the key (whether it's held or not), check for when it's pressed or realesed. It can be done by saving the keys previous state and checking if its state has changed, or by using the event loop.

Using key states:

```
was_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

while True:
    pygame.event.pump()  # process event queue
    key_is_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if key_is_pressed[pygame.K_UP] and not was_pressed[pygame.K_UP]:
        current_pos[1] -= 1

    elif key_is_pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT] and not was_pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        current_pos[0] += 1

    elif key_is_pressed[pygame.K_DOWN] and not was_pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        current_pos[1] += 1

    elif key_is_pressed[pygame.K_LEFT] and not was_pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        current_pos[0] -= 1

    was_pressed = key_is_pressed
```

Using event loop:

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                current_pos[1] -= 1
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                current_pos[0] += 1
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                current_pos[1] += 1
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                current_pos[0] -= 1
```